# Chef server installation error during test

Tags: chef-infra

I installed Chef server on one of the clones created using VM Virtual box in Ubuntu with Windows 10. I encounter the following problem while testing the server:

```
manideep@manideep-VirtualBox:~$ sudo chef-server-ctl test

[sudo] password for manideep: 
Configuring logging...

Creating platform...
Configured URL: https://manideep-VirtualBox
Creating org pedant_testorg_manideep-VirtualBox_2786
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc-chef-pedant/lib/pedant/platform.rb:336:in `block in create_org': Bad error code 400 from create     org: {"error":["Field 'name' invalid"]} (RuntimeError)
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc-chef-pedant/lib/pedant/platform.rb:321:in `times'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc-chef-pedant/lib/pedant/platform.rb:321:in `create_org'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc-chef-pedant/lib/pedant/platform.rb:123:in `org_from_config'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc-chef-pedant/lib/pedant/platform.rb:42:in `initialize'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc-chef-pedant/lib/pedant.rb:79:in `new'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc-chef-pedant/lib/pedant.rb:79:in `create_platform'
    from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc-chef-pedant/lib/pedant.rb:58:in `setup'
    from ./bin/oc-chef-pedant:10:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Does it work other than that?

Comment: it started working form me , after I reconfigred my chef manage installation

Answer (score 0):

May be the hostname having upper-case in it or any special symbol.  I had same issue while chef-server-ctl test but I've removed the - from hostname. And that worked.

There may any configuration parameter in chef for hostname= no uppercase or any special symbol.